# How useCallback in React optimizes performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The React docs claims that "useCallback is a React Hook that lets you cache a function definition between re-renders."

How is it possible to cache function definitions? This example is taken from React docs:

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react';

export default function ProductPage({ productId, referrer, theme }) {
  const handleSubmit = useCallback((orderDetails) => {
    post('/product/' + productId + '/buy', {
      referrer,
      orderDetails,
    });
  }, [productid, referrer]);
```

How is it possible to prevent the callback passed to `useCAllback` from being created? As far as I know, the JS runtime will create a new instance of the callback each time the `ProductPage` function is called (I have tested this behavior in JavaScript code).

What is `useCallback` optimizing? I also assumed that React calls the `ProductPage` function on every render.

I have searched Stackoverflow and google. I expect an explanation on why using `useCallback` is beneficiary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's re-order the questions a little:

> How is it possible to prevent the callback passed to `useCallback` from being created?

It is not possible. The function `ProductPage` is called every time the component is instantiated, which creates a new instance of the `(orderDetails) => { ... }` callback.

But – when we use `useCallback`, React uses the previous value unless any of the deps has changed, essentially throwing away the new instance.

> How is it possible to cache function definitions?

It's caching the value of the function itself. A standard dynamic cache would require an extra unique key to store/retrieve the cached value; since React's rules of hooks ensure that each instance of a hook within a component instance has a fixed position, there is no explicit cache key required.

> What is `useCallback` optimizing?

`useCallback` stabilises the callback value – essentially, the function doesn't change unless it needs to change because one of the dependencies has changed.

On its own, this doesn't optimise anything – there is, of course, a cost associated with tracking the cached value and its dependencies. If, however, the callback is passed to other components or hooks, then it may cause re-rendering or other work. A self-contained if slightly contrived example:

```js
function useNotifier(instances, value) {
  // Notify all instances when value changes

  const notifyAll = useCallback((value) => {
    instances.forEach(instance => instance.notify(value));
  }, [instances]);

  useEffect(() => {
    notifyAll(value);
  }, [notifyAll, value]);
}
```

If we don't stabilise `notifyAll` using `useCallback`, then the value of the callback changes every time the hook is rendered, even if the `instances` and `value` have stayed the same.

The `useCallback` docs do go into better explanations of the situations in which stabilising a function using `useCallback` (and similarly `useMemo`) can reduce the amount of work done in re-renders, in particular a couple of [deep dives](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useCallback#should-you-add-usecallback-everywhere) towards the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

> How is it possible to prevent the callback passed to `useCallback` from being created?

It's not possible, you're right on that. But that's not what `useCallback` is aiming at.

The optimisation that `useCallback` enables is when using `handleSubmit` (i.e. the return value of `useCallback`) as a dependency of other hooks, e.g. `useMemo` or `useEffect`. But on its own, it's pretty useless.